# How to use queried table name in subquery

Tags: firebird, correlated-subquery, firebird2.5

I'm trying to query field names as well as their maximum length in their corresponding table with a single query - is it at all possible? I've read about correlated subqueries, but I couldn't get the desired result.

Here is the query I have so far:

```sql
select T1.RDB$FIELD_NAME, T2.RDB$FIELD_NAME, T2.RDB$RELATION_NAME as tabName, T1.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID, T1.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH, 
    (select max(char_length(T2.RDB$FIELD_NAME)) 
     FROM tabName as MaxLength)
from RDB$FIELDS T1, RDB$RELATION_FIELDS T2
```

The above doesn't work because, of course, here the subquery tries to find "tabName" table. My guess is that I should use some kind of joins, but my SQL skills are very limited in this matter.

The origin of the request is that I want to apply [this script](https://www.sbzsystems.com/general-help-issues/databases-issues-and-tips/change-varchar-character-set-to-utf8-in-firebird-database/) in order to transform all my non-utf8 fields to UTF8 but I run into "string truncation" issues, as I have a few `VARCHAR(8192)' fields that lead to string truncation errors with the script. Usually, none of the fields would actually use these 8192 chars, but I'd rather make sure before truncating.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do cannot be done this way. It looks like you want to obtain the actual maximum length of fields in tables, but you cannot dynamically reference table and column names like this; being able to do that would be a SQL injection heaven. In addition, your use of a SQL-89 cross join instead of an inner join (preferably in SQL-92 style) causes other problems, as you will combine fields incorrectly (as a Cartesian product).

Instead you need to write PSQL to dynamically build and execute the statement to obtain the lengths (using [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execblock) (or a stored procedure) and [`EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt)).

For example, something like this:

```sql
execute block
  returns (
    table_name varchar(63) character set unicode_fss, 
    column_name varchar(63) character set unicode_fss, 
    type varchar(10), 
    length smallint,
    charset_name varchar(63) character set unicode_fss,
    collation_name varchar(63) character set unicode_fss,
    max_length smallint)
as
begin
    for select 
      trim(rrf.RDB$RELATION_NAME) as table_name, 
      trim(rrf.RDB$FIELD_NAME) as column_name, 
      case rf.RDB$FIELD_TYPE when 14 then 'CHAR' when 37 then 'VARCHAR' end as type, 
      coalesce(rf.RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH, rf.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH / rcs.RDB$BYTES_PER_CHARACTER) as length,
      trim(rcs.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME) as charset_name,
      trim(rc.RDB$COLLATION_NAME) as collation_name
    from RDB$RELATIONS rr 
    inner join RDB$RELATION_FIELDS rrf 
      on rrf.RDB$RELATION_NAME = rr.RDB$RELATION_NAME
    inner join RDB$FIELDS rf 
      on rf.RDB$FIELD_NAME = rrf.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE 
    inner join RDB$CHARACTER_SETS rcs 
      on rcs.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID = rf.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID
    left join RDB$COLLATIONS rc 
      on rc.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID = rf.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID 
      and rc.RDB$COLLATION_ID = rf.RDB$COLLATION_ID 
      and rc.RDB$COLLATION_NAME <> rcs.RDB$DEFAULT_COLLATE_NAME 
    where coalesce(rr.RDB$RELATION_TYPE, 0) = 0 and coalesce(rr.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG, 0) = 0
    and rf.RDB$FIELD_TYPE in (14 /* char */, 37 /* varchar */)
    into table_name, column_name, type, length, charset_name, collation_name
    do
    begin
        execute statement 'select max(character_length("' || replace(column_name, '"', '""') || '")) from "' || replace(table_name, '"', '""') || '"'
          into max_length;
        suspend;
    end
end
```

As an aside, the maximum length of a VARCHAR of character set UTF8 is 8191, not 8192.